# SQL aggregate functions and Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

**Employee**
empId
empName
empStoreNum

**Invoice**
invNo
invAmount
empId

I have two tables above Employee and Invoice. I would like to setup a query to retrieve employee names, employee store numbers, and the total sales for each employee. I have issue a query below and it works but I was not able to retrieve employee store number.

```
SELECT Emp.empName, Sum(Inv.invAmount) AS totalSales
  FROM Invoice AS Inv INNER JOIN Employee AS Emp ON Inv.empId = Emp.empId
 GROUP BY Emp.empName
```

If I add Emp.empStoreNum to the SELECT I get the following error:  “You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression ‘empStoreNum’ as part of an aggregate function.” How can modify the query to get employee store number also?

Comment: So what is it? MySQL, SQL Server, or Access? Syntax is different, and you should use the tags that actually apply to your question and not just grab everything vaguely applicable. Think of it this way: you have a friend that speaks one language, and your question is "How do I say <something>?". Wouldn't it be better to tag it with the language your friend speaks (eg., Spanish) instead of tagging it French, English, Spanish, and German?

Comment: @KenWhite: if I had to guess, the user is transferring from MySQL where it 'worked' to MS SQL Server (or MS Access, or both) where it doesn't because of the difference between MySQL and most of the rest of the world w.r.t GROUP BY lists.  But that is a guess.

Answer (score 2):

All non-aggregate columns in the select-list must be listed in the GROUP BY clause (unless you're using MySQL, which plays by a very different set of rules, or unless you are using a sufficiently recent version of PostgreSQL, which is able to deduce functional dependencies).

```
SELECT Emp.empName, Emp.empStoreNum, Sum(Inv.invAmount) AS totalSales
  FROM Invoice AS Inv INNER JOIN Employee AS Emp ON Inv.empId = Emp.empId
 GROUP BY Emp.empName, Emp.empStoreNum
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding empStoreNum to `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT Emp.empName, Emp.empStoreNum, Sum(Inv.invAmount) AS totalSales
FROM Invoice AS Inv INNER JOIN Employee AS Emp ON Inv.empId = Emp.empId
GROUP BY Emp.empName, Emp.empStoreNum
```

Answer (score 1):

Add that second column to your group by

Comment: I'd like to up-vote your answer; you have the kernel of the answer there, but the explanation is really a little too terse to warrant an up-vote.

Comment: That's no problem. The important part is that you got your answer :-)